# "If you don't have a fresh chicken, I'll take a frozen (one)." – When can an adjective act on behalf of a whole noun phrase?

Tags: adjectives, ellipses

Consider these sentences:

> 1. If you haven't got a fresh chicken, I'll take a frozen.
> 2. If you haven't got a fresh chicken, I'll take the frozen.
> 3. If you haven't got fresh cream, I'll take canned.
> 4. If you haven't got (any) fresh cream, I'll take some canned.
> 5. If you haven't got fresh cream, I'll take the canned.

As you see, *frozen* and *canned* are adjectives that are used attributively but their accompanying nouns are left out. Is it grammatical to do so? Under what conditions? Does the phrase remain a noun phrase?

Of course, the problem can be detoured by adding back the omitted nouns (*frozen chicken/one, canned cream*), but the question is, cannot the adjectives do alone?

You can also share your native impression and tell us (preferably in the comment section) which of the sentences above you find acceptable and which unnatural.

Comment: Yes, it's grammatical, as in your examples, or like this: *I need some cream. If you don't have fresh, canned is fine.*

Comment: @TRomano I don't think it's true as a general rule; cf, "_I don't like this doll. Give me a beautiful._"

Comment: Your counterexample does not follow the original pattern you presented, "this doll" is hardly the same as "fresh chicken". Also, "it's" in your comment lacks a clear antecedent.

Comment: The adjectives involved should be ones which semantically admit an opposition, as in "I don't like sweet wine, I like dry.  He doesn't want canned peas, he wants fresh. She likes red wine, he likes white.  He likes flashy cars, she prefers reliable".

Comment: There are also species of adjective; for example, **fresh**, **beautiful**, **mistaken**, and **excrescent** express their respective properties in very different ways.

Comment: "I don't want an ugly doll, I want a beautiful" would be the same form as what you are arguing for, yet it categorically doesn't work.

Comment: Have you read what CGEL has to say about fused modifier-heads?

Comment: @snailplane It does discuss my question fairly thoroughly in Ch.5, §9.3, and also mentions it  in Ch.6, §2.4.1.b. It would take a while for me to shape a self-standing answer out of all that, but I guess I'm going to do it sometime. Thank you.

Comment: @Mari-LouA OK, I'll try. And thanks for the attraction!

Comment: OMG, the post has been viewed only 312 times! But I am glad that the questions and answers have all earned upvotes. Now, your question asked which sentences were acceptable and natural, in which case my decision is easy. But someone actually *explained* the semantics, or the grammar if you prefer,  and that makes my choice a bit more difficult. The bounty will be awarded before "tomorrow" nevertheless. And this comment should appease any who happen to disagree with me.

Answer (score 11):

Natural:

> If you haven't got (any) fresh chicken, I'll take frozen.
>
> If you haven't got fresh cream, I'll take canned.
>
> If you haven't got any fresh cream, I'll take (some) canned.

Not natural:

> If you haven't got a fresh chicken, I'll take a frozen

(***one*** is needed)

By adding the singular article **a**, you also need to point towards a singular chicken using **one**. (Or indeed you could just say "chicken" again.) When you omit the article, there is no requirement to do this.

Comment: Tom, I've downvoted the answer because your statement that "**one** is needed" does not jibe with my experience.  I hear phrases analogous to "I'll take a frozen" quite often. Since it's November: "If you haven't got a fresh turkey, I guess I'll have to take *a frozen*".

Comment: @TRomano I'm not rejecting your opinion, but Tom [is not alone](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33487775#33487775) in thinking _one_ is needed after _a frozen_. So maybe it's a regional thing?

Comment: I disagree with the example using "some". It should be handled the same as when an article is used. But I am not sure what "***some** (not needed)*" means. If you are saying a word is optional, put that word in parenthesis. For example, my guess is "If you haven't got any fresh cream, I'll take (some) canned." in the case where using *some* is optional.

Comment: **Some** is legit if the speaker has a countable in mind. Maybe he would buy several cans of cream if there is no fresh cream available. *If you have no cream donuts left, I'll take some chocolate.*

Comment: Mari-Lou/user3169 - It seems my notation was unclear, so have changed at as per user3169's suggestion :) TRomano - I think "I'll take a frozen" almost works in the case of a chicken, but certainly not with say "i'll take a beautiful" (doll). I think I stand by my original statement that one is needed.

Comment: @TomB +1 In British English that's certainly the case. I can't downvote the comment saying otherwise, but I would if I could.

Comment: I think the distinction is a matter of singular, plural and mass nouns. With singular nouns like a doll and plural nouns like cars the word _one_ or _ones_ may be optional but it is always implied. In the case of mass nouns, however, there is nothing to count so _one_ or _ones_ cannot be used. Cream is a mass noun, chcken can be either. If you haven't any fresh chicken I'll take _a_ frozen _one_" is fine with or without either or both of the words in italics. "Some" is an optional word with mass nouns and plural ones We can say "This fabric is ugly, show me some beautiful _ones_".

Comment: It’s interesting so much is been said about the numbers of nouns, fungibility or other absorbing issues…

Meanwhile it’s not explicitly but only by quiet example that BoldBen shows us “got” shouldn’t be there; the true form should be “If you haven't any fresh chicken I'll take a frozen one" or “if you have no…”

I mention this not because I’m sticking up for old fashioned rules but because I fear that in far too few years, everything said here will become of only historical, academic interest in the same way that “got” snuck unhelpfully into the wrong place hardly 100 years ago.

Comment: Actually I didn't know that "have got" was frowned upon, although I can see that the "got" is redundant. Do you have a link with more information? Nonetheless, small redundancies and whatnot are always going to creep into languages, it's part of how they evolve.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - Sounds like a *completely* different question. Feel free to ask it as one if you want; these comments are not the place for that discussion.

Answer (score 9):

**TL;DR:** See the bulleted list in the second quotation box, and maybe peek into the final list too.

---

Sentences #1-5 in the original post are examples of the *fused-head* construction; more specifically, the *fused modifier-head* construction.

> Fused-head noun phrases are those where the head is combined with a dependent function that
>   in ordinary noun phrases is adjacent to the head, usually determiner or internal modifier:
>
> `- i` *Where are the sausages? Did you buy [some] yesterday?*  [determiner-head]
>   `-ii` *The first candidate performed well, but [the second] did not.* [modifier-head]

<sup>(from *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL) by Huddleston and Pullum, p 410)</sup>

*Some* in `i` above is a determiner *and* the head of its noun phrase at the same time; *second* in `ii` is simultaneously a modifier and the head.

With a few exceptions, almost all determiners can occur in this construction. But the case of modifier-heads is a little more complicated:

> 7.3 **Fused modifier-heads**
>
> Fusion of **modifier** and head of an NP is seen in the following examples, where an adjective serves as modifier and as head at the same time:
>
> `-  i` *Should I wear the red shirt or [the blue]?*
>   `- ii` *[The youngest of their children] was still at school.*
>   `-iii` *[The French] don 't take these things too seriously.*
>
> In [i] we understand *the blue* to mean "the blue shirt".
>    In [ii] the reference is to the youngest member of the set consisting of their children.
>    In [iii] *the French* has a special interpretation: it means French people in general.
>
> Modifiers cannot fuse with the head as readily as determiners can. Examples like
>   these are not grammatical:
>   `-  i` **Kim had hoped for a favourable review, but Pat wrote [a critical].*
>   `- ii` **That mattress is very soft: I 'd prefer [a hard].*
>   `-iii` **Look through this box of screws and pick out [some small].*
>
> Instead of the fused-head construction in cases like these we use an NP with ***one*** as head: *a critical one*, *a hard one*, *some small ones*.
>
> The modifiers which most readily fuse with the head include these:
>
> - **determinatives†** used in modifier function following a determiner (e.g. *these **two***)
> - **superlatives** and **comparatives** (*the **best***, *the most **important** of them*, *the **taller** of them*)
> - **ordinal** numeral words (*the **second***, *the **eighth***)
> - certain semantic categories of **adjective**, e.g. colour adjectives as in *the **blue*** and nationality adjectives that aren't also count nouns, as in *the **French***, *the **English***, *the **Dutch*** (we don't get **The Belgian are very courteous* because we use the count noun instead: *The Belgians are very courteous*).
>
> ---
>
> <sup>**†** A category of words (or lexemes) which can function as **determiner** in an NP, marking it as **definite** or **indefinite**: *the*, *a*, *this*, *that*, *some*, *any*, *few*, etc. Most can occur with other functions too: e.g., *that* is modifier of an
>   adjective in *It wasn't that great*.</sup>

<sup>(from *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar* by Huddleston and Pullum, pp 99-100 and p 298)</sup>

*CGEL* expands a great deal on the subject. Here's a short summary:

- The determinatives *every* and *various* **cannot** function as modifier-heads.
- Indefinite comparatives **cannot** be modifier-heads too; so this is ungrammatical:
  **Hugo has a big house, but Karl has [a bigger].*
- Modifiers denoting color, provenance, and composition **can** act as modifier-heads:
  *I prefer cotton shirts to [nylon].*

  - However, there is significant loss of acceptability when the determiner is indefinite; eg, sentences #1 and #4 in the original post:
    <sup>?</sup>*If you haven't got a fresh chicken, I'll take a frozen*
    <sup>?</sup>*If you haven't got (any) fresh cream, I'll take some canned*.
- Adjectives denoting basic physical properties such as age and size **can** also act as modifier-heads:
  *Lucie likes young/big dogs, but I prefer [old/small].*

  - But the acceptability is lost with indefinitely determined NPs:
    **Lucie bought a young dog, but I bought [an old]*.
    And it's lost or degraded with adjectives denoting more complex physical properties or with evaluative adjectives, for example those denoting character:
    <sup>?</sup>*Lucie likes smooth-coated dogs, but I prefer [shaggy].*
    **Lucie likes friendly dogs, but I prefer [aggressive].*
- A rather restricted range of adjectives beyond those covered above
  occur in fused-head constructions with special interpretations; eg:
  *[The French] do these differently from [the Dutch].*
  *[The rich] cannot enter the kingdom of Heaven.*
  *This is verging on [the immoral].*
  *They like to swim in [the nude].*

---

For a fuller discussion and detailed explanation of the exceptions, refer to *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, pp 415-418, or if you were in the mood, pp 410-425.

And thanks to @snailplane for [a helpful hint](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/359560/if-you-dont-have-a-fresh-chicken-ill-take-a-frozen-one-when-can-an-adj#comment836444_359560).

Comment: Helpful and interesting post!

Answer (score 5):

You ask "Does the phrase remain a noun phrase?"  Yes, because the reduced phrase can be the antecedent for the "it" or "them", when you continue any of your examples with "Because I like it/them almost as well."  I couldn't figure out the main part of your question, however.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just wondering whether the concept of 'fungibility' is useful here: "If there's no brown sugar, I'll take white." (Just to get away from the chicken and cream).

As long as the first adjective refers to a fungible, the second one doesn't need a 'prop' word. Once you take away the fungibility in the first clause - by whatever means - you force the use of a similar specifier in the second clause.

In the original question, only no. 3 seems natural to me.

Comment: I've always thought of cream as being fungible

Comment: sorry, I thought the idea here was to contribute, not snipe at other contributors

Answer (score 2):

All of your sentences are in need of a a [pro-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-form) since you do not want to repeat the actual noun. A pro-form is a stand in for another phrase where the meaning is recoverable from context. The way your sentences are structured this is an *assertive existential quantifier,* meaning you are not referring to a specific chicken or cream, but you just assume its existence.

> If you have chicken/cream, I'll take *one/some*.

In your case you are adding an adjective to give that pro-form another property (frozen or canned) juxtaposing the property from the first part of the sentence.

> (1) If you haven't got a **fresh** *chicken*, I'll take a **frozen** *one*. (singular)
>
> (1b) If you haven't got a **fresh** *chicken*, I'll take the **frozen** *one*. (singular, specific)
>
> (2) If you haven't got (any) **fresh** *cream*, I'll take *(some)* **canned**. (uncountable)
>
> (2b) If you haven't got (any) **fresh** *cream*, I'll take *(the)* **canned**. (uncountable, specific)
>
> (3) If you haven't got (any) **fresh** *chicken*, I'll take *(some)* **frozen** *ones*. (plural)
>
> (3b) If you haven't got (any) **fresh** *chicken*, I'll take *(these)* **frozen** *ones*. (plural, specific)

The reason people are calling for the word *one* is an English pecularity. The word *one* is a [prop-word](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prop-word) which excels at standing in on pro-forms. I cannot speak to how idiomatic it is where to skip that prop-word. However most languages don't have one and would just nominalize the adjective. [English used to do the same.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalized_adjective#Historical_development) Anyhow it is clear that there is no such word for uncountable nouns which is why no one called for changes in your *cream-example*.

Anyhow the ellipsis of this prop-word might be highly regional in English and this construction sounds very idiomatic ESL speakers whose native language is bigger on nominalizing adjectives than English, which is essentially every language.

A prerequisite to use an adjective in the second part of the sentence in any such way you need one in the first part to contrast it to.

> If you haven't got chicken, I'll take a frozen (one). (Makes no sense.)

Another prerequisite is that the adjective is describing a property of the object in question. I can't quite put my finger on it but it seems to not work properly with limiter adjectives like real, perfect and adjectives that are subjective like interesting, beautiful, pretty. On the contrast it works very good with very definite adjectives like your frozen.

Comment: While the extra information provided in the first half is much appreciated, you start answering the question directly in the second (namely, the last three paragraphs). This would discourage the casual reader from seeing your answer through. A _TL;DR_ or slight reorganization could help, IMO.